# Algorithm for finding change in progression of two sets of arrays

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that will search for a change in the progression of two sets of numbers with the same length. The set starts at the same number all the time. For example:

```
Assumptions:
1. Arrays 1 and 2 are the same length
2. Progressions are not available at the start, and need to be computed. But computing it will be expensive with resources.

Array 1 [1, 3, 5, 7, 10]
Progression: +2, +2, +2, +3

Array 2 [1, 2, 4, 6, 5]
Progression: +1, +2, +2, -1

Result: Array or numbers deviates on first progression by -1 and last progression by -4.
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to any sort of linear search?

Comment: You want only the result in progression difference between two arrays considering only their first and last indices?

Comment: Not just considering the first and last index. I'm thinking if there's something like a binary search algorithm that I could use to determine, given two arrays with the same length, on which numbers did their progressions differ.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only concerned with the first and last deviations you can search from the front of the list until you find the first deviation (if you don't find one then you obviously don't need to do the second step), and then search from the end of the list until you either find the last one, or reach the position where you found the first one (in which case there is only 1 deviation).

However, I don't believe you can do it without any sort of linear search, and in the worst case you would end up having to check every single deviation.